# Can't get HTML background to change based on JSON API variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, api

```
    function getWeather(lat, lon){ 
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
          currentTempInCelsius =parseInt(myObj.main.temp);
          document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML =currentTempInCelsius;
        backImage(parseInt(myObj.main.temp));                                     
       }
       };
 xmlhttp.open("GET", urlString, true);      
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In that first function I get the current temperature from the API, which I parse and pass on to backImage. Then I apply an if loop to assign a css class (.cold, .avg & .body) which holds the url to the background-image to the body, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function backImage(tempp){
if(tempp<15){
  setImg(cold);
  }
  if(tempp>=15&&tempp<25){
  setImg(avg);
  }
  if(tempp>=25){
  setImg(hot);
  }
}

function setImg(myClass){
   $('body').className = myClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setImg(myClass){
   $('body').removeClass();
   $('body').addClass(myClass);
}
```

Try to this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, although it makes sense to remove class first

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
   function setImage(myClass) { 
     $('body').toggleClass(myClass);
}
```

As mentioned in the [API Documentation of Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) this function:

*adds or removes one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements...*